# Argument of type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request'

Tags: typescript, next.js

Here's the issue I get from typescript:

```
Argument of type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request'.
  Type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to type '{ url: string; }'.
    Types of property 'url' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
(parameter) req: NextApiRequest
```

I'm having the following error with `req` in my `await graphqlHTTP({...})(req, res)` request.

```js
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  await graphqlHTTP({ graphiql: true, rootValue, schema })(req, res)
}
```

My code compiles fine, and works as intentioned, I'd just like to fix the error showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either to ensure that *req.url* actually has a value since it can be undefined, or require that type of *req* is compatible with NextApiRequest but requires a value for url.

**Ensure that url is not nullish**

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.url) {
    await graphqlHTTP({ graphiql: true, rootValue, schema })(req, res);
  }
}
```

**Require that they type of object passed has a defined url**

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest & { url: string }, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  await graphqlHTTP({ graphiql: true, rootValue, schema })(req, res);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is perfect and I now understood the issue.